# Surjection and Bijection of linear transformation

Tags: linear-transformations

Let there be V,W vector spaces above field F. $T:V--->W$ linear transformation.
(v1,v2,v3....vk) $\subseteq$ V.
-->$span({T(v1),T(v2)...T(vk)})=W$.
true or false:

1. If T Surjective then $span(v1,v2...vk)=V$
2. if T Bijective then span $(v1,v2...vk)=V$

if i understand the question correctly if i take the group v1-vk to be 3 vectors ${(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0)}$,and lets say the $T(v)={{(4,0,0,0),(0,4,0,0),(0,0,4,0)}}$. that means my transformation is surjective and bijective and both statements are false. What am i missing here ? thank you in advance :)

Comment: @ThomasAnton THANK YOU, i was bashing my head for 2 hours on that ! :)))

Comment: You should be clear and define $T$ however. It's not a linear map yet since you haven't said what happens to the fourth basis vector. Even though it's pretty clear.

Comment: But in my example of disapproval, Do i have to define T ? I mean does it really matters what t does to the forth vector ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question and said the wrong thing. If $W=\mathbb{R}^4$, then it isn't spanned by $(4,0,0,0)$, $(0,4,0,0)$ and $(0,0,4,0)$. For example $(0,0,0,1)$ is not in their span. I have deleted the previous response for clarity.

Comment: @ThomasAnton in my example W vectors are: $(a,b,c,0)$ and it is in fact spanned by $(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0)$. the image of the transformation in my example will always be $(a,b,c,0)$, is it still wrong to consider both false?I mean W doesn't has to be a $(a,b,c,d)$ vector space, $(a,b,c,0)$ still adheres to the vector space rules...

Comment: Are both $V$ and $W$ the set of vectors $(a,b,c,0)$? Because then as you point out, $V$ is then spanned by your vectors, so you don't have a counterexample. If $V$ is the set of vectors $(a,b,c,d)$ then you have a counterexample for $T$ being surjective, but now $T$, if you gave it a full definition, cannot be bijective. Also, I would just use $W$ as the set of all vectors $(a,b,c)$, as using four coordinates suggests you're in $\mathbb{R}^4$.